# ListView.separated trailing icons all show CircularProgressIndicator instead of just the one that was tapped

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm using a ListView.separated and when the user taps the download button, it's supposed to show a CircularProgressIndicator(); while the file is being downloaded and then return to a download button when the download is over. It works but then ALL the buttons on the ListTile() transform to the CircularProgressIndicator(); and not just the file being downloaded. How to fix this? Or is there a way to pass index to the trailing parameter?

```dart
ListView.separated(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final file = files[index];
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        file.name,
      ),
      subtitle: const Text(
        '123456789',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.black),
      ),
      trailing: !isDownloading
          ? IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.download_rounded,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isDownloading = true;
                });
                downloadFile(index, file);
                setState(() {
                  isDownloading = false;
                });
              })
          : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (_, index) =>
      const SizedBox(height: 15),
  itemCount: files.length,
);
```

I tried wrapping it in a builder but that wouldn't work

Comment: You have only one "isDownloading".  You need one for each item.  Consider a custom widget that has all your update logic internally as state, and use that in your builder so each subwidget gets their own downloading state.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a list of booleans to track the download state of each item. Here's yours modified example:-

```
  ListView.separated(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
    final file = files[index];
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(file.name),
      subtitle: const Text(
        '123456789',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
          fontSize: 12,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: isDownloading[index]
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.download_rounded),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isDownloading[index] = true;
                });

                //Add your download process (replace this with your actual download logic)
                Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                  setState(() {
                    isDownloading[index] = false;
                  });
                });
              },
            ),
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => SizedBox(height: 15),
  itemCount: files.length,
);
```

we use a list called isDownloading to monitor the download state for each item. When a download starts for a particular item, only that item's state is marked as "downloading," displaying a progress indicator for that item. After the download is finished, the item's state is reset, and the download button returns to its normal state. This allows individual tracking of download progress for each item in the list.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I agree with this solution, seem to meet the requirements